# Download a PNG file from HTTP endpoint with query string

Tags: java, jersey

Sorry for the poor title.

I have a URL like this:
http://testserver:8080/dummy/server?@_1231Fv_C

When I access this URL using browser, this returns me a PNG image. 
But, when I try to fetch it using Jersey client API, I can't download it.  (I tried java.nio as well)

See my code snippet

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.setFollowRedirects(true);
WebResource r = client.resource(url);
InputStream in = r.get (InputStream.class);
ByteStreams.copy(in, new FileOutputStream(savedFile));
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How does the failure show up? Do you get an exception stack trace?

Comment: There is no failure or exception.

Answer (score 1):

`@` characters are reserved, maybe you should encode them (change it to `%40`).

- [URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)
- [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Guava library?
Then it's worth to note that `ByteStreams.copy` Copies all bytes from the input stream to the output stream. **Does not close or flush either stream**.

You Should flush & close your FileOutputStream.

It will be better if you share more details e.g Exceptions etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing like this and its working

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@Path("/image")
public class ImageService {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:\\az-fu.png";

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("image/png")
    public Response getFile() {

        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=image_from_server.png");
        return response.build();

    }

}
```

Dialog when I hit from web browser:

[image: Dialog when I hit from web browser]